# Split list of lists into smaller lists with a function

Tags: list, function, user-input, nested-lists

I have this long list of lists (274 elements), this is a short section of the list:

```
    ['HR03', 'Jadranska Hrvatska', '8.5'],
    ['HR04', 'Kontinentalna Hrvatska', '8.8'],
    ['HU31', 'Eszak-Magyarorszag', '-2.9'],
    ['HU32', 'Eszak-Alfold', '-0.3'],
    ['HU33', 'Del-Alfold', '0.3'],
    ['IE01', 'Border. Midland and Western', '4.9'],
    ['IE02', 'Southern and Eastern', '4.8'],
```

I have a task where I'm supposed to create a function where the user input creates a new list. Eg. the user input "HU" would create the list:

```
 ['HU31', 'Eszak-Magyarorszag', '-2.9'],
 ['HU32', 'Eszak-Alfold', '-0.3']
 ['HU33', 'Del-Alfold', '0.3'],
```

The user input "IE" would create a list with all the elements that starts with "IE01", "IE02" and so on. 
I'm completely lost here. I have no idea how to do this, and my textbook doesn't explain it either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension with a condition should do the trick

```
lst = # data...
prefix = input("Enter a prefix: ")
result = [x if x[0].startswith(prefix) for x in lst]
```